# Having trouble rendering backbone.js collection view. Getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'on' of undefined" in my initialize function

Tags: javascript, html, json, backbone.js

I am new to backbone.js and am having trouble pin pointing why my view is undefined on line 67 of coupons.js. I posted a gist as they are pretty long files.

Also, if I refresh the browser a bunch of times, eventually it works just fine and then I refresh again and it breaks and I can refresh again until it works and then again until it breaks. Painful cycle.

[Gist for coupons.js and offers.js](https://gist.github.com/8f90e84f20eaf4e50557)

Comment: It just means your model doesn't exist. Are you sure you are creating the models correctly and then passing them to `CouponView` (or another view?)

Comment: i mean i think so? my other ones work? and it even works _sometimes_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error occurs when you try to call a method on an object that's null/undefined.  The issue is that your call to fetch data for `offerList` is asynchronous, but you're instantiating the collection view synchronously.  That is, this in `CouponCollectionView`'s constructor :

```
this.collection.on('add remove', this.render, this);
```

is getting called while the collection is still null:

```
var coupons = null;
$.getJSON('http://localhost:3000/api/coupons.json', function(response){
    coupons = new CouponCollection(response);
    app.coupons = coupons;
});
```

You might want to consider using `var coupons  = new CouponCollection()`, and calling `coupons.fetch()` -- that way, the collection will be instantiated immediately, and ready for your `on` call in the View.

---

Set up the collection so that you can call `fetch`:

```
var CouponCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Coupon,

    // tell Backbone where to send the "fetch" request
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/coupons.json'
});
```

Instantiate the collection immediately, and call `fetch` on it:

```
var coupons = new CouponCollection();
coupons.fetch();
```

Add a `reset` listener to the collection (triggers when `fetch` is complete), and render the view in the handler:

```
this.couponCollectionView = new app.CouponCollectionView({collection: this.couponList});
var self = this;
this.couponList.on("reset", function() {
    $('#content').empty().append(self.couponCollectionView.render().el);
});
```

Comment: sorry if this is pretty n00by, but where do you suggest i add that? i understand what you mean, but am not totally sure how to implement that.

Comment: @ohwutup in general you'd want to add a `reset` listener to your collection, where you render the view.  Then call `fetch()` -- that way the view renders when its data is ready.

Comment: thanks man, i am going to try this, but am probably guaranteed to have a few more questions. im new to js and even newer to backbone. having trouble making it up the learning curve.

Comment: okay so its working, but now i am getting the same type of error with my redeemers collection. is it possible to add in another url for my collection or do i need to make a new `Backbone.Collection` entirely? i updated my gist [here](https://gist.github.com/8f90e84f20eaf4e50557).

Comment: @ohwutup keep in mind you can specify `url` as a function if you like, but still, I think it's best just to create a new `Backbone.Collection`.